# Woocommerce, как получить свои атрибуты циклом внутри цикла?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

в шаблон для боковой панели делается выборка категорий товаров, заданных в плагине и нужно реализовать еще выборку своих полей для данных категорий. С этим моментом застрял, прошу помощи.
шаблон:

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <!--парсим категории в магазине-->
  <?php
  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
      $orderby      = 'name';
      $show_count   = 0;
      $pad_counts   = 0;
      $hierarchical = 0;
      $title        = '';
      $empty        = 0;

      $args = array(
             'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
             'orderby'      => $orderby,
             'show_count'   => $show_count,
             'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
             'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
             'title_li'     => $title,
             'hide_empty'   => $empty
      );
     $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
     foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
            $category_id = $cat->term_id;
                    ?>
                <!--и делаем их ссылками-->
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header">
                        <p class="openSemi black-text">
                            <?php echo $cat->name ?>
                        </p>
                        <div class="triangle-cover hide"></div>
                        <div class="triangle hide"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                        <?php
                            $goodsArgs = array(
    //                          тут указываем его тип
                            'post_type' => 'product',
                                'product_cat' => $cat->name,
                                 'hide_empty'   => 0,
                                 'post_per_page' => 1
                            );
         $i=0;
    //                              запускаем
                            $wc_query = new WP_Query( $goodsArgs );
                                    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
                                    $wc_query->the_post();
                                     global $product;

                                    $mans = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_manufacturer');
    // тут вот категории должны бы превращаться в чекбоксы для дальнейшей обработки, но не превращаются 
                                    foreach($mans as $manufacturer) {
                        ?>
                            <p class="exo2Medium black-text">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo 'manufacturer ' . $i; ?>" />
                                <label class="exo2Medium black-text" for="<?php echo 'manufacturer ' . $i; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $manufacturer->name; ?>
                                </label>
                            </p>
                            <?php
                             $i++;
                            };
            endwhile;
         wp_reset_postdata();

                        ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?
            } wp_reset_query();
            ?>

        </ul>
```

Уже испробовано:

аналог текущего кода на родной функции для вукомерса тоже был испробован, результат такой же - атрибуты (производитель) выводятся только для вбитых товаров:

```
<?php
                    $goodsArgs = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                        'product_cat' => $cat->name,
                         'hide_empty'   => 0,
                         'post_per_page' => 1
                    );
 $i=0;
                    $wc_query = new WP_Query( $goodsArgs );
                            while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
                            $wc_query->the_post();
                             global $product;
                            $mans = wc_get_product_terms( $post->ID, 'pa_manufacturer', false );
                            foreach($mans as $manufacturer) {
                ?>
                    <p class="exo2Medium black-text">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo 'manufacturer ' . $i; ?>" />
                        <label class="exo2Medium black-text" for="<?php echo 'manufacturer ' . $i; ?>">
                        <?php echo $manufacturer; ?>
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <?php
                                 $i++;
                            };
                            endwhile;
 wp_reset_postdata();

                ?>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?
    } wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

и еще вариант:

```
    $mans = get_terms("pa_manufacturer");
    $i = 0;
    foreach($mans as $manufacturer) {
    ?>
<p class="exo2Medium black-text">
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo 'manufacturer ' . $i; ?>" />
<label class="exo2Medium black-text" for="<?php echo 'manufacturer ' . $i; ?>">
    <?php echo $manufacturer->name; ?>
</label>
</p>
<?php $i++; };
```

Выводило атрибуты для вбитого в админке товара, но уже без определения категории, не подошло.

Что я упускаю? Буду благодарен за помощь / направление в нужные маны. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам.
Оставлю тут на случай, если кому пригодится:
во втором цикле, который вызывает нужный атрибут, в зависимости от категории товаров нужно использовать тот же цикл и за счёт переменных разделить вывод под каждую отдельную категорию:

```
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <!--парсим категории в магазине-->
        <?php
  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';
  $show_count   = 0;
  $pad_counts   = 0;
  $hierarchical = 0;
  $title        = '';
  $empty        = 0;
  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
        $i; $a; $b;
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
     $i++;
     if ($i == 1) {
                ?>
            <!--и делаем их ссылками-->
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header">
                    <p class="openSemi black-text">
                        <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
                    </p>
                    <div class="triangle-cover hide"></div>
                    <div class="triangle hide"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">
<!--                выбираем нужный атрибут, преддварительно добавив его в админ-панели сайта-->
                    <?php
        $goodsArgs = array(
         'taxonomy'     => 'pa_manufacturer_out',
         'hide_empty'   => 0
        );
//       объявляем переменную. нужно для работы чекбоксов
         $b=0;
                 global $product;
                $mans = get_terms( $goodsArgs );
                 foreach($mans as $manufacturer) {
                    ?>
                        <p class="exo2Medium black-text">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo 'manufacturerOut ' . $b; ?>" />
                            <label class="exo2Medium black-text" for="<?php echo 'manufacturerOut ' . $b; ?>">
                                <?php echo $manufacturer->name; ?>
                            </label>
                        </p>
                        <?php
                $b++;
                };

                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?
         } else { ?>
<!--         повторяем для других атрибутов-->
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header">
                        <p class="openSemi black-text">
                            <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
                        </p>
                        <div class="triangle-cover hide"></div>
                        <div class="triangle hide"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                        <?php
                        $goodsArgs = array(
         'taxonomy'     => 'pa_manufacturer_inner',
         'hide_empty'   => 0
                        );
         $a=0;
         global $product;
         $mans = get_terms( $goodsArgs );
         foreach($mans as $manufacturer) {
                    ?>
                            <p class="exo2Medium black-text">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo 'manufacturerInner ' . $a; ?>" />
                                <label class="exo2Medium black-text" for="<?php echo 'manufacturerInner ' . $a; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $manufacturer->name; ?>
                                </label>
                            </p>
                            <?php
        $a++;
                                };

                    ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php }
//   сбрасываем переменную цикла
        } wp_reset_query();
        ?>

    </ul>
```